# Is possible run --code-coverage or similar command to run coverage during ng serve in Ionic/Angular app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, code-coverage

I need to registry coverage result during `ng serve` to retrieve coverage report without karma test.
I know during karma it is possible but I need to registry this report in serve mode.